# Setting language array as constant

Tags: php

My site is translated using language files, such as "en/home.php" which inside has content such as...

```
<?php
$lang = array(
'welcome' => 'Welcome to DugoutSoccer.com',
'login' => 'Login',
'pw' => 'Password'
);
?>
```

In several functions I make $lang global and wanted to save the need for this (if it's worth it). The files can be as large as 25Kb, would it be acceptable to define this as a constant?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically just normal defintion of Constant and unseralizing the constant...

```
# define constant, serialize array
define ("ConstantVar", serialize (array ('welcome' => 'Welcome to DugoutSoccer.com',
'login' => 'Login',
'pw' => 'Password')));

# use it
$my_constant= unserialize (ConstantVar);
```

Comment: sorry, I don't think I explained myself very well. I know how to make it a constant, I was asking is it worth doing for a large array of 25Kb? P.s. In PHP 7 you don't need to serialize

Comment: @DugoutSoccer yes it is! Constants are inexpensive!